# How to find out Mac OS X version from Terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, version

I know how to find Mac OS X version from GUI:

> Apple Menu (top left) > About This Mac

Is there a Terminal command that will tell me Mac OS X version?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

You have a few options:

```
sw_vers -productVersion 

system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
```

Either will do what you need, and will have an output format that's parseable (if that's what you're after).

Comment: The first one only gives you the OS version (ie, "10.7.5").  The second one gives you a lot of additional information such as 32/64-bit.

Comment: Nice one! I was going made looking for `lsb_release` or something along those lines. Never would have spotted those scripts. :D

Comment: The two commands do not output the version name like `Monterey`

Answer (score 10):

The command `sw_vers` shows the version.

For older Mac OS's you can find useful information in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29).

Answer (score 5):

If all you care about is the major version (10.10, 10.9), you can do

```
MAJOR_MAC_VERSION=$(sw_vers -productVersion | awk -F '.' '{print $1 "." $2}')
```

I use this in a couple of scripts that have to do different things if run on 10.8.x, 10.9.x and now 10.10.

Comment: Simpler: `sw_vers -productVersion | cut -d '.' -f 1,2`

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to split the macOS version number based on semantic versioning for script logic, here is a small snip of code I use

```
product_version=$(sw_vers -productVersion)
os_vers=( ${product_version//./ } )
os_vers_major="${os_vers[0]}"
os_vers_minor="${os_vers[1]}"
os_vers_patch="${os_vers[2]}"
os_vers_build=$(sw_vers -buildVersion)

# Sample semver output
echo "${os_vers_major}.${os_vers_minor}.${os_vers_patch}+${os_vers_build}"
# 10.12.6+16G29
```

You can use these variables in script logic to run different commands based on the version of macOS. This gives slightly more granular control down to the patch or build version.

```
# Sample bash code
if [[ ${os_vers_minor} -ge 11 ]]; then
    DMG_FORMAT=ULFO
elif [[ ${os_vers_minor} -ge 4 ]]; then
    DMG_FORMAT=UDBZ
else
    DMG_FORMAT=UDZO
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The information is stored in `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`, you don't need the `sw_vers` tool for that. Especially if you want to access the version of an external drive you attached and didn't boot from.

Comment: That's actually quite cool! When was this featurette added? It certainly works under Big Sur 11.7.9, but I wonder if it's the kind of thing that has always been there?

Comment: I think it's been there for ages, but i can't tell since when. There's a sample file at: https://opensource.apple.com/source/DarwinTools/DarwinTools-1/SystemVersion.plist.auto.html and it states 10.4, which is pretty much from the earliest days of macOS