# OS X remote home directories

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I have two Macs - a Mini and a MacBook Pro. They are both running Snow Leopard (neither is OS X Server). I have a 10TB LaCie NAS.

Is it possible to setup remote home directories? I want one remote directory per account so that if I log in as `jzaun` on either Mac, I get the same directory. I would also like to be able to be logged in to both machines at the same time with the same account.

I'm looking to do this so all my preferences and files etc are the same regardless of which computer I'm logged into.

I don't have any other computers to run Linux (and really no desire to setup OpenLDAP or similar software). I'm looking to do this with no additional software/hardware at all, if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Configure a Remote Home Directory on Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/16129/how-to-configure-a-remote-home-directory-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: [another duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/40164/sharing-or-syncing-home-folders-between-macs).

Comment: @Daniel Beck - Um its not, That first linked question is in regards to Windows and having a the mac use it. the second duplicate is about syncing... I dont want to sync I want the files to sit on the network.

Comment: [possibly related](http://superuser.com/questions/253704/use-one-home-directory-for-more-than-one-operating-system/259513#259513)

Comment: "*I would also like to be able to be logged in to both machines at the same time with the same account.*" — sorry, but you're *really* asking for trouble here, since software doesn't generally reload its preferences files when it's running. Additionally, while you have  `ByHost` preferences, I don't think they're respected by a lot of third party devs.

Answer (score -1):

Open LDAP with your home directory stored on a server is really the way to go.  OSX server is set up to do this with GUI.  I hear Lion will have these tools installed by default.