# How to get my Mac's specifications without the Apple menu icon?

Tags: macos, mac

I deleted the Apple menu (with "About this Mac") from my Mac's menu bar. As a result have no idea about what the Operating System is, how many gigs of ram it is running, etc.

How can I get the information I am looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out Mac OS X version from Terminal?](http://superuser.com/questions/75166/how-to-find-out-mac-os-x-version-from-terminal)

Comment: Next time please ask one question per post. This is very messy now.

Comment: I want to know how you managed to delete "About this Mac"… as it's not even an App in its own right, it's a window in System Information; brought up with Cmd/i Did you trash System Information?

Comment: I've removed your question about how to restore it. Please ask a new question for that, and please explain how you removed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can go into **→** Applications **→** Utilities and open up **System Information** (or press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to start Spotlight and just type **System Information**).

The System Information application will tell you all about the properties of your Mac, and also shows your missing "About this Mac" through menu Window, or by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: Yes OP deleted `About this Mac` you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The information available in **About this Mac** can also be found using the `system_profiler` command in Terminal.

`system_profiler`, run without any arguments, will take a while and probably output more information than you need. You can provide one or more datatypes as arguments to reduce the level of output to the information you need. Some examples related to your question are:

`system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType` will show you information about your Operating System, such as your current OS version.

`system_profiler SPHardwareDataType` will show you information about your hardware, such as how much RAM is installed.

You can optionally combine multiple datatypes in a single command to combine the output:
`system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType SPHardwareDataType`

To discover other available datatypes, `system_profiler -listDataTypes` will output a complete list.
Run `man system_profiler` for more detailed information on how to use this command.